# How to upgrade from Windows 8.0 to 8.1 while keeping all the apps?

Tags: windows-8

I installed Windows 8.1 from within Window 8 and noticed my apps don't work anymore, some are gone and a ton of stuff is missing. Is there no way to keep all the Windows settings and apps when doing this upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to Windows 8.1 from windows 8 without losing apps is possible. There are two things to note here 1) The installation language must match your system's default UI language and 2) a specific Windows 8 edition can only be upgraded to its equivalent or higher edition.

For example, if you have Windows 8 Pro English-GB installed, then you can only upgrade to Windows 8.1 Pro English-GB  or Windows 8.1 Enterprise English-GB without compromising application data.

I found this information at [this link](http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-upgrade-to-windows-8-1-without-losing-apps/) and it worked for me.

Comment: Went back to see what versions I was using. I was trying to install the Pro version on top of Enterprise. I guess that's the problem. Then I decided I wasn't going to upgrade after all. I just have too many customizations and don't want the risk of losing anything.