# Will the Windows Store update from Windows 8 to 8.1 leave all my data/apps intact?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I want to update to windows 8.1 from the Windows 8 installation that came with my computer. In Windows Store I see that there is an update to 8.1 (about 3.6GB). Will all my files, programs, apps, and data remain as they were in Windows 8?  Normally when you install windows on a computer without it, all the data on the C drive is removed, will this happen with the 8.1 update from the Windows Store?

Comment: The update is a seamless process.  The correct name your looking for is the `Windows Store` not the "Windows Market".  This information is also on the Windows website front and center ( its also been asked before ).

Comment: @Ramhound what is seamless? please write on simple word english )

Comment: I did use a "simple" word. Seamless means `smooth and without seams` in other words. You install the update, your computer boots, and afterwords its exactly how you left it except its now running Windows 8.1.  As I already pointed out this particular question has been asked and answered before.  Its also clearly documented on the Microsoft website.

Comment: @Ramhound As long as there isn't another question on SU about this, then it is a legitimate question.

Comment: @zeel - Except it has been asked before. I will admit the question is with regards to Windows 8.1 Preview but the question with regards to going fromt he Preview to the RTM has also been asked. I personally have written answers on both topics, on this very website, incase that wasn't evident.  This question ( http://superuser.com/questions/649485/how-to-upgrade-from-windows-8-0-to-8-1-while-keeping-all-the-apps?rq=1 ), is close enough, to be considered a duplicate in my eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update from Windows 8 to 8.1 your Windows configurations, files, and most apps will follow along but it is always a good idea to have a backup of your files just in case. I updated as well some time ago and had no problems.

Source: [Windows 8/8.1 FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8) and [Updating from Windows 8 to 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial)
Ps. I couldn't find the source in English, though you can use Google Translate if you need.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you install Win 8.1 from Windows Store then you don't have to worry about your data because IT's Just An Update.

- While you install it from ISO or DVD Image you perform a clean install
  (i.e. deleting c drive). I've updated to 8.1 on my colleague's Sony Vio and no issue with it. You'll be safe if you will follow on screen instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 8.1 update is designed to be an "in place" update, just like service packs in previous versions of windows (in fact, 8.1 is a service pack, they just aren't calling it that). This means that when you install 8.1 on a Windows 8 machine there should be no changes to your data or software.

You do have the option of running a clean installation if you wish, which would remove all data like a traditional OS installation, but this is not required. In a typical case there should not be any changes.

Please note that on some systems (especially laptops) there may be certain drivers and software that you will need to update/re install for them to work properly with Windows 8.1, and failure to properly prepare for the update may cause problems that would require a full re-installation to fix. Be sure to check the manufactures website for information about upgrading your specific model.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all desktop applications, your personal files and Modern Apps will continue to work in Windows 8.1. However, maybe some metro apps will need to be re-downloaded. NOTHING is deleted.